# Recovering .ipa file for TestFlight app on iOS 8 (not jailbroken)

Tags: ios

Normally if I want to see the binary and resources for an app, I connect my iPhone to my Macbook, sync with iTunes, and then all of my apps are in /Users/cybergibbons/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications as .ipa files which I can extract as zips.

I have recently been given access to a beta version of an app via TestFlight. Whilst TestFlight is in the above location, there is no evidence of the beta app.

How do I go about getting the .ipa for the TestFlight app?

Comment: Have you tried using iFunBox or iTools ?

Comment: I have tried the OP's method as well as using iExplorer and had no luck. Using iOS 8.4 JailBroken. iFunBox worked for me. User Applications -> Right Click on App -> Backup to .ipa package.